# Sharepoint Online REST api CAML query not returning file related columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, rest, caml

I'm trying to query a document list from a SharePoint Online server using REST API.

I have to use CAML, otherwise filtering is not possible on the taxonomy field as far as I know.

Below is the request I send to sharepoint, it returns the rows, but the columns **FileRef, FSObjType, EncodedAbsUtl, FileLeafRef** are missing from the result set.

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('docstore')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1=
{ 
"ViewXml": "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
            <ViewFields>
              <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>
              <FieldRef Name='FileRef'/>
              <FieldRef Name='FSObjType'/>
              <FieldRef Name='EncodedAbsUrl'/>
            </ViewFields>
            <Query>
              <Where>
                <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name='ma7b4d79a8904f3685c6d9fe04f38d1d'/>
                  <Value Type='TaxonomyFieldType'>TaxName|b6e32b49-9e02-4f65-98dc-3a6049eb03c3</Value>
                </Eq>
              </Where>
            </Query>
          </View>"
}
```

Comment: I believe you are supposed to pass the Name of your List columns there.

Comment: How do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to explicitly load the columns (e.g., **FileRef**):

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('docstore')/GetItems(query=@v1)?**$select=FileRef&**@v1=
{ 
"ViewXml": "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
```